# No option to edit Stack Exchange profile or close account

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, stackexchange.com

I'm trying to edit my profile on the main stackexchange.com site, but I don't have the option to edit my profile. I'd like to change the display name, and if I cannot do that then I'd like to delete my account.

I've followed the directions below, but I don't have the 'Edit Profile & Settings' tab.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

How can I edit my profile or close my account?

Comment: does this link work for you? https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ issue here is with stackexchange.com itself which indeed has no way to edit the profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have observed here is, when you sign up with Stack Overflow, an account on Stack Exchange is automatically created. You also don't need to join Stack Exchange website explicitly. Therefore, there is no profile information available for your Stack Exchange account as it is the encompassing network.

So, if you want to edit your profile name, you can do it for all other websites that fall within the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

To edit your main Stack Exchange profile you could do this steps:

1. Open your [Meta.StackExchange profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).
2. Edit your meta profile information as you want.
3. Save these changes with one of the available buttons from the bottom of the profile page 
   [image: save buttons]
4. Open your main Stack Exchange profile by clicking the `Network profile` link
   [image: Network profile]
5. Click on **Update profile info**
   [image: Update profile info]
6. Choose **Meta Stack Exchange** from the dropdown list 
   [image: dropdown list]
7. Click the **Copy** button