# Why is it so hard to edit my profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web, network-profile, profile-sync

I just spent the last 10 minutes trying to figure out how to edit my profile. I'm using the phone/mobile version of the site, and its possible the problem is limited to that.

From any individual SE site, I can view my profile. But when I try to "update" the profile (the only option available) it simply asks which other SE site I want to import from. I don't want to import, I want to type new info.

Even from the top-level SE page, and even on the meta, it just gives me a read-only version of my profile.

The only way I found to actually "edit" my info was in the first comment in this question here:

[No option to edit Stack Exchange profile or close account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319298/no-option-to-edit-stack-exchange-profile-or-close-account)

Is this hard-to-find comment the only way to edit my profile?

Shouldn't I be able to find this page within two clicks of ANY SE page, assuming I am already logged in?

In response to Shadow Wizard's answer, I am posting the results of their step 1. Can you please direct me to the link you are telling me to follow in step 2?

> [image: screenshot of the a network user profile page]

This following screenshot is in response to rene's answer. Despite rene's helpful information in (now deleted) comments, I believe the comments to be impractical. Where's the link you are talking about?

> [image: screenshot of a user profile on Electrical Engineering]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to one of your site profiles, like Electrical Engineering, and scroll to the links at the bottom of the page then click “full site”.

> [image: Screenshot of links at the bottom of the page when browsing mobile page]

Then scroll to the top left of the page and choose the edit profile and settings tab.

> [image: Screenshot of the edit tab selected]

Change whatever needs changing, then choose the appropriate “save” option at the bottom of the page.

> [image: Save for just this community, save and copy to all communities]

Then, scroll to the bottom of the page and choose “mobile” if you prefer the less functional mobile web page over the fully functional responsive design pages.

If you are using the “full site” pages with responsive design enabled it’s not difficult to edit your profile. If you have to use the old mobile pages for some reason, it’s more difficult because you have to switch.

Some browsers have a “Request desktop site” feature, which might make it easier to switch, but that doesn’t work to switch me to “full site” mode (maybe because SE remembers my choice instead of letting the browser undo it, which is a good thing).

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not hard. It's two clicks away, on any site. Two.

1. Clicking your profile picture or badge count on the top bar
2. Clicking "Edit profile and settings" in the profile page

That is it. Two clicks and you're in the profile edit page where you can change the information.

As for mobile, the mobile theme is old and not really useable, like the mobile apps [its development is frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/135565) and it's deprecated. Don't use it, but rather tap the "full site" link in your mobile and you'll enjoy the responsive design which is already in place much more.

Comment: @geek I already got some good information from both you and rene in comments that are now deleted. But I'm going to play along here. Editing the question. I'm going to add a screenshot of what I see when I complete your step 1 and ask you where is the link you are directing me to use in step two.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore that's because you're probably in stackexchange.com which is only the portal, not Q&A site on its own, hence has no profile of its own.

Answer (score 2):

This is very much by design.

You can only edit your settings / info in a per site user profile. The network account with its about me, site and display name is just there for convenience.

The general idea is that users only have to bother with settings on the site(s) they joined.  This also allows for having different info per site.

If anything, maybe the link should read *Synchronize profile info* so it sets the right expectation.

There is no way to edit your profile from the mobile view. Switch to the full site first (link is at the bottom of the page).
When you're on your network profile you can click accounts and then pick any site listed there to land on your per site user profile. There you can make the changes you prefer on the *edit profile and settings* tab. Once completed you can go back to your network profile and choose to Update where you select the site you edited your info on. That is 6 to 8 clicks.

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look at my question and the information you provided in the (now deleted) comments. I am posting another screenshot of what I see in my per site profile, *engineering* in this case. Can you please direct me to the "edit profile and settings" button you are referring to?

Comment: @AldusBumblebore it is only available in the full site view, not in the mobile view. I've added that step.